# Text under mouse cursor on PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I have a problem with displaying the text under the mouse cursor on Picture Box.
I want to dynamically display the mouse coordinates under the cursor.

I'm trying to display text by label and change the label's position when a "MouseMove" event happens.

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        label1.Location = new Point(e.X + 10, e.Y + 10);
    }
```

But, I think, it is a bad solution...
And although it works it hides other output when we move the cursor

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you think it's a bad solution? I personally would do the same :)

Comment: I think that using MouseMove is a bad 'move'. You get many events in rapid sequence and moving an object as simple as a label is very time consuming

Comment: Maybe you can use a ToolTip? I'm not sure if it offers all the methods you'll need, but it might be worth giving it a try.

Comment: Yes I agree with thomas...its much better from performance point of view that instead of anyother event, you can use tooltip which is light weighted work around...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Thomas's advice, here code to display mouse coordinate under cursor:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.SetToolTip(pic, " ");
tt.ShowAlways = true;

 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    tt.ToolTipTitle = e.X + "  " + e.Y; 
 }
```